# Such contrast - What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

So big so small,
So old, so new
So short, so tall.
Dry, or covered in dew.

Used everywhere,
Destroyed but saved.
Happiness or despair,
When I am razed.

Trust me, I know
Really, I'm near.
Every arrow and bow
Earned its shape, dear.

Comment: Apparently today is not my day... That was fast.

Comment: It was good, though!

Comment: Such contrast, so riddle, wow!

Comment: So, downvoters, any reason why aside from it was easy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be

> a tree or a forest of trees

I would add explanations, but it's all self-explanatory.

> also, the first letters of the last stanza spell TREE

Comment: Drat. Well, you and leoll2 were so close, I'll give the answe to the first one to find the hidden clue.

Comment: i think i already found it and added it to my answer

Comment: That was fast....

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a

> Tree

So big so small,
So old, so new
So short, so tall.
Dry, or covered in dew.

> Those adjectives perfectly fit for a tree.

Used everywhere,
Destroyed but saved.
Happiness or despair,
When I am razed.

> Wood has many applications. Forests are destroyed by many, protected by others. Cutting a tree is bad for the planet, but good for paper industry.

Trust me, I know
Really, I'm near.
Every arrow and bow
Earned its shape, dear.

> Arrows and bows are made of wood.

*Easter Egg:*

> In the last stanza, the initials of each line form the word "Tree".

Comment: Drat. Well, you and JLee were so close, I'll give the answe to the first one to find the hidden clue.

Comment: @AggieKid The last stanza initials form the word Tree

Comment: That was fast....

Comment: @AggieKidd lol, split pot!